# movie trailer youtube search_query

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

can anyone please tell me how i could get the first youtube video link result of my ?search_query=SEARCH 
Example:
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=hangover+2009+trailer

The first results link is:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcdUhdOlz9M

Can anyone please tell me how i could do this with jquery? I am willing to get youtubes movie trailer link based on search_query.

Cause this links can be used in iframe afterwards to display in my page.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tcdUhdOlz9M" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Thank you!!

Comment: please use a server.. if you don't know how to build your own please use [diff bot](https://www.diffbot.com/dev/docs/article/)

Answer (score 1):

It is simple. After you integrate your code with Youtube API, it will return an object like result which you can set almost everything with API (amount of results, date, so more). So, based on that you can shape it like you want in view.

Below is a jQuery example with some treatments in result:

```
function tplawesome(e,t){res=e;for(var n=0;n<t.length;n++){res=res.replace(/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/g,function(e,r){return t[n][r]})}return res}

$(function() {
    $("#search-btn").on("click", function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
        //prepare the request
        var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
            part: "snippet",
            type: "video",
            q: encodeURIComponent($("#input-search").val()).replace(/%20/g, "+"),
            maxResults: 6,
            order: "viewCount",
            publishedAfter: "2015-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        });
        request.execute(function(response){
            var results = response.result;

            function getMonth(monthNumber){
                var monthName = ['jan', 'fevereiro', 'mar', 'abr', 'mai', 'jun', 'jul', 'ago', 'set', 'out', 'nov', 'dez'];

                return monthName[monthNumber-1];
            }

            var dateUTC = results.items[0].snippet.publishedAt;
            var year = dateUTC.substring(0,4);
            var day = dateUTC.substring(8,10);
            var month = dateUTC.substring(5,7);
            month = getMonth(month);

            var finalDate = day + " de " + month + " de " + year;


            console.log("passou", results.items[0].snippet.description);
            //$.each(results.items, function(index, item){
            $.get("youtube/item", function(data){ 
                $("#results").append(tplawesome(data, [{ "videoId":results.items[0].id.videoId}]));
            });
            $.get("youtube/title", function(data){ 
                $(".info-title").append(tplawesome(data,[{"title": results.items[0].snippet.title, "videoId":results.items[0].id.videoId}]));
            });
            $.get("youtube/description", function(data){ 
                $(".info-description").append(tplawesome(data,[{"description": results.items[0].snippet.description, "videoId":results.items[0].id.videoId}]));
            });
            $.get("youtube/finalDate", function(data){ 
                $(".publishedTime").append(tplawesome(data, [{finalDate}]));
            });

            $.get("youtube/relationVideo", function(data){ 
                $(".relationVideo-container").append(tplawesome(data,[{"title": results.items[1].snippet.title, "videoId":results.items[1].id.videoId}]));
            }); 
            $.get("youtube/relationVideo", function(data){ 
                $(".relationVideo-container").append(tplawesome(data,[{"title": results.items[2].snippet.title, "videoId":results.items[2].id.videoId}]));
            }); 
        });
    });
});

function init (){    gapi.client.setApiKey("AIzaSyDuLpwiCe78V9p0JE5rQaygB2XVgIDHjhs");
    gapi.client.load("youtube", "v3", function(){
       //youtube API ok 
    });
}

$( document ).ready(function(){
    $("#search-btn").on("click", function(){
       $('#info-section').addClass('show');
        $('#video-section').addClass('show');
        $('#description-section').addClass('show');
    });
```

You can see a simple project with Youtube API, NodeJS and Express [here](https://github.com/aipi/reampYoutubeAPI/blob/master/public/js/this.js).

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to integrate the YouTube API instead: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

But if you want to do as you describe above, you could get that page and then scrape the results: basically find something unique about the search results, target that with a jquery selector, then get the data you want from the element.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
function searchByKeyword() {
  var results = YouTube.Search.list('id,snippet', {q: 'hangover+2009+trailer', maxResults: 1});
  return results.items[0];
}
```